# Is there an HTTP status code for (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)?

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-5

if there isn't, I need to know how to capture that error in my applicaion and display a suitable message to the user. I am using mvc5

Answer (score 1):

If the error is because the server is misconfigured, or something else server side, that would be a 500 series error, or just the basic 500 "server messed up" error. This suggests there's nothing the user can do to fix this error.

If the error is because of something that the client is passing in the request, then it's a 400 series error, ideally with some text telling the user what they can change to make the request process properly.

Comment: I used the following code in the web.config file to redirect the user to the corresponding error page and it still didn't redirect him properly.    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/DatabaseDown"/>
    </customErrors>